# Using Middleman Tags

Tags: middleman

I am wondering if someone could explain how I can utilise tags in an article.

The documentation states that by default the blog extension should allow you to access tagged articles via tags/blogging.html. http://middlemanapp.com/guides/blog
I guess I'm not sure if I need to create this dir (tags/blogging.html) or if its generated for me?

Then I'm wondering how to create a list of tags, each with a URL that points to this tag template.

I've added this example tag data to the front matter of a few of my articles.

```
--- 
title: My Middleman Blog Post
date: 2011/10/18
category: music
tags: blogging, middleman, hello, world
---
```

my index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<section class="article-index music">
    <% data.blog.articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
        <% if article.category == 'music' %>
            <article>
            <h2><a href="<%= article.url.sub('.html','') %>"><%= article.title %></a></h2>
            <time pubdate><%= article.date.strftime('%b %e') %></time>
            <span class="categories"><%= article.tags %></span>
            <%= article.summary %>
            </article>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</section>
```

This is outputting all my articles, with a title, date, all tags and a summary.

I'm assuming you need to loop through all the tags and output each in a URL of its own, but I'm not really sure of the best way to do this.

At a guess I'm assuming its something like:

```
<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <a href="/tags/#{tag}.html">tag</a>
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported in 2.0. Possibly in upcoming 3.0

Answer (score 3):

By combining the other answers I have come up with this solution.

```
<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

It has the benefit of using a generated path, rather than the hardcoded one.

Answer (score 2):

Tags for all articles can be retrieved with the following:

```
<% blog.tags.each do |tag, articles| %>
  <%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %> (<%= articles.size %>)<br />
<% end %>
```

This is exactly what I have on my blog:-

[Blog](http://www.dahal.co/archive.html)

[Github](https://github.com/dahal/dahal.github.io/blob/source/source/archive.html.erb)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you'd have to do it like so:

```
<% article.tags.split(", ").each do |tag| %>
  <a href="/tags/#{tag}.html">tag</a>
<% end %>
```

Assuming your tags are separated with a comma and a space.

Answer (score 1):

I write my tags in the frontmatter as an array

```
tags           : [ accessibility, standards ]
```

Then I can just loop through them

In HAML it would ne

```
- current_page.data.tags.each do | tag |
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me in HAML for just displaying the tags, no links

```
%p= article.tags.join(', ')
```